# Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What do I need to change in order to make this work? Sorry, I am fairly new to VBA.

```
Sub DoCopyExample3()

    Dim szRange As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    Dim Country As Variant


    szRange = "C1:C6"



    For Each Country In Worksheets("Result").Range("A10:A12").Cells

    counter = 3

    Worksheets("Summary").Cell(C1).Value = Country

    Worksheets("Summary").Range(szRange).Copy

    Worksheets("Result").Cells(1, counter).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Result").Cells(1, counter).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    counter = counter + 1

    Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
Worksheets("Summary").Cell(C1).Value = Country
```

with:

```
Worksheets("Summary").Range("C1").Value = Country
```

*There may be other errors.*

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary's Student, that is exactly what was blocking me. Great help!

Comment: Stupid question... how do i bring out a positive vote for you?